# Is delta lake supported by spark2.xx

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

So i was trying to use delta lake write    `df_concat.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("file") it gives me this error` :

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/connector/catalog/TableProvider
and delta lake doc says update to spark3 so just want to confirm if we can run deltalake on spark2.xx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Delta release 0.6.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.delta/delta-core_2.12/0.6.1) - the latest that supported Spark 2.x.  You need to have at least Spark 2.4.2 to run it.  Just run your code with `--packages io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.6.1`, or link it to the application