# How to add Delta Lake support to Zeppelin's spark interpreter?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, delta-lake

I'm trying to add the Delta Lake support to Zeppelin.

So far I've tried adding the `io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0` dependency to the spark interpreter, as well as a couple other related actions within the interpreters view... but nothing has worked.

When I add the `io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0` dependency, I get errors within my notebooks such as:

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:76)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:668)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:577)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:130)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler.lambda$runJobInScheduler$0(FIFOScheduler.java:39)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.stringToSeq(Utils.scala:2664)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigHelpers$.stringToSeq(ConfigBuilder.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder$$anonfun$toSequence$1.apply(ConfigBuilder.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder$$anonfun$toSequence$1.apply(ConfigBuilder.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.createWithDefault(ConfigBuilder.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<init>(SparkConf.scala:716)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<clinit>(SparkConf.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$loadFromSystemProperties$3.apply(SparkConf.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$loadFromSystemProperties$3.apply(SparkConf.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:877)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:468)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:468)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:876)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.loadFromSystemProperties(SparkConf.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:58)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:80)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    ... 8 more
```

My goal is to read/write from/to Delta Lake tables using Scala + Spark.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of spark and scala are u using ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable reason for this is that you're using Delta Lake with Spark 2.x - the package that you're using is supposed to work with Spark 3.0+ (compiled with Scala 2.12).  The latest version of Delta that supports 2.4 (minimum 2.4.2) is 0.6.1 (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132284/is-delta-lake-supported-by-spark2-xx/63133575#63133575)).

So you need to upgrade Spark version if you want to use this specific package, or use another version of Delta if you want to keep you Spark installations.