# Apache Spark: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError V2TableWithV1Fallback

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

My setup is:

Spark version 3.1.2
Using Scala version 2.12.10, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 11.0.11

pip3 packages:
delta-spark            1.0.0
findspark              1.4.2
pyspark                3.1.2

To my knowledge, these versions should be compatible?

Trying to follow the example like this:

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/ole/spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop3.2')
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from delta import *

builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
data = spark.range(0,5)
data.write.format("delta").save("/tmp/delta-table")
```

Gives me the error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o123.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/connector/catalog/V2TableWithV1Fallback
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.getTable(DeltaDataSource.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.getTableFromProvider(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.getTable$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:322)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:384)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:287)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure that you're using Spark 3.1.2? your `findspark.init` points to 3.0.1, for which you need to take Delta 0.8.0

Comment: You where right. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

I think your version of delta isn't compatible with your version of spark.

Look at the reply from Alex on [Is delta lake supported by spark2.xx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132284/is-delta-lake-supported-by-spark2-xx)

Other thing to be considered if you have included `--packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0` while running your code

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the reply. Looking at https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html it says delta lake 1.0.x should be compatible with spark 3.1.x. Am I missing something here? Should I try an older version of spark?

Comment: did you include ```--packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0``` while running your code?

Comment: When doing a submit of the job? I would like to run this locally on my computer to test code. How would this be done with jupyter notebook for ex.?

Comment: you can find that info on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684856/import-pyspark-packages-with-a-regular-jupyter-notebook . let me know if it works for you!!